# What does error "The name :1.36 was not provided by any .service files" mean?

Tags: gnome, evolution

Sometimes my Evolution mail will stop syncing with my Google contacts and calendars, and will give me this error message.

> The name :1.36 was not provided by any .service files

When Googling this error, it turns out that it comes up in other software too, such as Sound Juicer.  But I'm getting it in Evolution.  Those are both Gnome apps, if that's relevant.

What could be the common thread between these instances of this cryptic error message, and does anyone know specifically what the error message means?

Usually I avoid this by re-creating the syncing between Evolution and Google, but that's an arduous process and I'd rather know what the error means so maybe it can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

This error could be related to a "lost" `gvfs` mount.
Some applications like evolution or nautilus use GVFS to mount remote service (ie. Gdrive, calendar and so on), as if it were a local resource.

Sometimes when your internet connection or a VPN, goes down, these GVFS connections get stuck and this cryptical error is showed.

I found very little info on how resolve this problem, it seems a strange bug related to GVFS (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1026884).

Other resources:
https://realtechtalk.com/gvfs_mount_in_runuser_cannot_be_accessed_or_displayed_wrong_permissions_Error_Location_is_already_mounted-2080-articles

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Kill the apps that misbehaved (it's not their fault).
2. `sudo killall gvfsd`
3. Restart the apparently misbehaving apps.